# Combine goal count in Google Analytics for Google sheets

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, analytics, google-analytics-api

I wish to make a report of the number of goals per month. There are 13 goals in the Analytics property of which 8 are releveant to the report. I use Analytics for Google sheets to create this report.

Is there a way to add up the number of goals completed? An example of something I'd like to use (these don't work):

```
ga:goalCompletionsAll - filter out goal 5, goal 6, goal 9, etcetera.
```

Or something likes this:

```
ga:goal2-14Completions
```

or

```
ga:goal2Completions & ga:goal3Completions & ga:goal4Completions & ga:goal5Completions
```

Thanks!

Comment: Due to the way google analytics works i would almost recommend that you request them one by one rather than combined.

Comment: At the moment I have them one by one but to add them up in the correct cells for the report is a hell of a job. :\

Comment: Welcome to the joy of Analytics :)

Comment: Managed to add them all op as efficient as possible. Still not a very efficient way of dealing with the data but does the trick :p

Comment: You might also want to keep in mind that, if your goal definition is overlapping (i.e., say, goal 1 is time on site > 1:00, and goal 2 is time on site > 2:00), the sum of the individual goal might not match the goalCompletitionsAll total. It is due to the session based nature of GA goals.